# «Я знаю, что то — ложь». Запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, грамматика, тире

Первый вопрос: нужна ли запятая после «то» («то, — ложь»)?
Второй вопрос: нужна ли запятая после «что» («что, то»)?

Answer (score 1):

***Я знаю, что то — ложь.***

Запись выглядит корректной. Запятая перед союзом ЧТО в сложноподчиненном предложении и интонационное тире между подлежащим ТО и сказуемым ЛОЖЬ.

Но предложение неполное, в таких случаях желателен контекст.